# Making a box challenge -Edabit (for loop returns wrong output.)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to solve [This question](https://edabit.com/challenge/jXJZoEXNF5jBvc7j4) on edabit. But my code returns the wrong output.

My code:

```
function charBox(s) {
    if(s % 1 !== 0 || s < 0 || typeof(s) === "string") return -1;
    let charArr = "#".repeat(s).split("");
    let res = [charArr];
    for(let i = 1; i < s; i++) res.push(res[0])
    
    if(res.length > 2) {
        for(let j = 1; j < res.length -1; j++)
            for(let k = 1; k < (res[j].length - 1); k++)
                res[j][k] = " ";
        return res;
    } 
    else return res;
}
```

Expected Output: *If input = 4*

```
charBox(4) ➞ [
  ["#", "#", "#", "#"],
  ["#", " ", " ", "#"],
  ["#", " ", " ", "#"],
  ["#", "#", "#", "#"]
]
```

My output: *If input = 4*

```
charBox(4) ➞ [
  ["#", " ", " ", "#"],
  ["#", " ", " ", "#"],
  ["#", " ", " ", "#"],
  ["#", " ", " ", "#"]
]
```

[Here's Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjnq6y4k/) if you wish to give it a try. *Please, Can someone explain how I'm being dumb.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 for loops. Check if the current coordinates are from the border items. The border condition is: at least one of `i, j, n-i-1, n-j-1` should be zero.

```js
function box(n) {
  const output = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const inner = []
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if ( [i, j, n-i-1, n-j-1].includes(0) )
        inner.push("#")
      else
        inner.push(" ")
    }
    output.push(inner)
  }
  
  return output
}

console.log(
  box(4)
)
```

You could also use nested `Array.from()` like this:

```js
const box = n => Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i) =>
  Array.from({ length: n }, (_, j) => 
    [i, j, n-i-1, n-j-1].includes(0) ? "#" : " ")
)

console.log(box(4))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Your solution is great! but, I still don't understand why my for loop fails... It changes every element in the array even when my index is set to begin from '1' and end at the second last element. Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: @bunee you are pushing the same array reference of `charArr` to all indexes. If you change one of the arrays, it affects all the inner arrays. Change your code to add a copy of the `charArr` using `slice`. Change the code: `let res = []; for(let i = 0; i < s; i++) res.push(charArr.slice())`

Comment: And here I was, Thinking my for loop was broken XD. Thank you! That makes much more sense. As a fellow Udupian myself, I respect you! Happy Coding :)